# Passing invididual field's "required" information to a compound Symfony2 form

Tags: php, forms, symfony, symfony-forms

I need to enter a pair of date and time in multiple places of my Symfony2 application. To accomplish this, I've created a `custom_datetime` form type. I'd like to decide whether `time` is required by occassion, while keeping `date` required if the whole custom_datetime has a `required` flag.

```
class DateTime extends AbstractType
{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('date', 'text', [
                'attr' => ['required' => true] // Here I maybe should inherit what is passed by the parent form
            ])
            ->add('time', 'text', [
                'attr' => ['required' => $options['time_required']]
            ])
        ;
    }

    public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'time_required' => false
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'custom_datetime';
    }
}
```

The `custom_datetime` is then by other forms. Currently I use it like this:

```
// date should be entered, time should not -- this does not currently work
$builder->add('dt', 'custom_datetime', ['required' => true, 'time_required' => false]);
// date + time should be entered
$builder->add('dt', 'custom_datetime', ['required' => true, 'time_required' => true]);
// neither of date or time is required
$builder->add('dt', 'custom_datetime', ['required' => false]);
```

Unfortunately the `time` field gets the required attribute when rendered in HTML.

**What should be done to allow the parent form of `custom_datetime` to pass "required" information about time field?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't use the `attr` attribute for this.

```
$builder
    ->add('time', 'text', array('required' => true))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer... just about to test and confirm. Simplicity... that's kind of rule of thumb everywhere, especially in programming. ;)

Comment: Yes, definitely this fixed my problem. Thank you once more.